# Codeigniter cart - adding item multiple times does not increment qty

Tags: codeigniter, cart

Im trying to add some item multiple times to cart, but added item doe's not appear in cart, if its already in it.

Is this normal in CI cart, or I messed up something?

How to workaround this?

I want same item added multiple times, in order to change price on second piece (special offers).

My cart_add function looks like example at codeigniter manual, I think there is no need to include code.

I found in cart class code, that cart row identifier (`$rowid`) is an md5 checksum generated from `id` and `options`. I temporarily added something like this to `options` array:

```
'options' => array('rid' => mt_rand(), ...)
```

but are there better ways? I feel im doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know you can't directly add/update the cart multiple times to make it's quantity increased. You need to do cart update by doing loop on cart contents. It's because CI will always create unique row_id on inserted product/item. `The reason a unique ID is created is so that identical products with different options can be managed by the cart`. For more clear you may refer to this **[article](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html)**.

Here you can do to update your cart item:

```
foreach($this->cart->contents() as $item){
    if($item['id'] == 'your_product_id'){
        $item['qty'] = 3;
        $this->cart->update($item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarify, but after CI Cart class code analysis i put random number into options array to force unique identifiers on every item "instance" added. I think that method will work faster (no loop) and anyway I need duplicated items in order to process special offer (same product in more than 1 price).

Comment: @Kamil sorry for late reply. It is true that it will be faster using your method since CI will only add it as different product (though only different options). It is based on your need. And you're welcome :)